# DataTables Row Grouping Subtotals

Tags: jquery, datatables

When my field has a space eg. firstname lastname, I can't Sum.
Also how do I number_format Totals on the column[0]? 
This example I found here:
[RowGrouping and Subtotal on Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657724/rowgrouping-and-subtotal-on-datatable/31675912#31675912)

https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6c3wzwcd/

I want

http://jsfiddle.net/alord84/ehup45xh/

```
 "drawCallback": function (settings) {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({
        page: 'current'
    }).nodes();
    var last = null;
    api.column(0, {
        page: 'current'
    }).data().each(function (group, i) {
        if (last !== group) {
            $(rows).eq(i).before(
            $("<tr></tr>", {
                "class": "group",
                "data-id": group
            }).append($("<td></td>", {
                "colspan": 5,
                "class": "pocell",
                "text": "PO # " + group
            })).append($("<td></td>", {
                "id": "e" + group,
                "class": "noCount",
                "text": "0.00"
            })).append($("<td></td>", {
                "id": "p" + group,
                "class": "noCount",
                "text": "0.00"
            })).append($("<td></td>", {
                "id": "b" + group,
                "class": "noCount",
                "text": "0.00"
            })).prop('outerHTML'));
            last = group;
        }
        val = api.row(api.row($(rows).eq(i)).index()).data();
        $("#e" + val.PO_Nbr).text(parseFloat($("#e" + val.PO_Nbr).text()) + parseFloat(val.Encum_Amt));
        $("#p" + val.PO_Nbr).text(parseFloat($("#p" + val.PO_Nbr).text()) + parseFloat(val.Paid));
        $("#b" + val.PO_Nbr).text(parseFloat($("#b" + val.PO_Nbr).text()) + parseFloat(val.Balance));
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the section of code that creates the totals uses an ID, and your ID has a space and thus burps.

This should work in your situation:

```
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({
        page: 'current'
    }).nodes();
    var last = null;
    api.column(0, {
        page: 'current'
    }).data().each(function (group, i) {
        group = group.split(' ').join('_')
        if (last !== group) {
            $(rows).eq(i).before(
                $("<tr></tr>", {
                    "class": "group",
                    "data-id": group
                }).append($("<td></td>", {
                    "colspan": 5,
                    "class": "pocell",
                    "text": "PO # " + group.split('_').join(' ')
                })).append($("<td></td>", {
                    "id": "e" + group,
                    "class": "noCount",
                    "text": "0.00"
                })).append($("<td></td>", {
                    "id": "p" + group,
                    "class": "noCount",
                    "text": "0.00"
                })).append($("<td></td>", {
                    "id": "b" + group,
                    "class": "noCount",
                    "text": "0.00"
                })).prop('outerHTML'));
            last = group;
        }
        val = api.row(api.row($(rows).eq(i)).index()).data();
        console.log(val);
        $("#e" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text(parseFloat($("#e" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text()) + parseFloat(val.Encum_Amt));
        $("#p" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text(parseFloat($("#p" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text()) + parseFloat(val.Paid));
        $("#b" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text(parseFloat($("#b" + val.PO_Nbr.split(' ').join('_')).text()) + parseFloat(val.Balance));
    });
}
```

If the spaces are removed from the ID and the comparison is made on the group without spaces then it should work as [you expect](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/0gr89pcd/).

Comment: Thanks! What about the situation where ->getFormatter is used ```var val = function ( a ) {
                return typeof a === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof a === 'number' ?
                        a : 0;
            };``` how do I remove formatting -------- ```var val = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };```

Comment: In the example I posted I replace spaces with underscores. This means that when it comes to outputting the name we can replace underscores with spaces to make it human readable. It doesn't really matter though. I did play with the idea of using a data attribute, `data-id`, on the row in the initial example and then searching for the cell with the correct class but thought better of it. Perhaps that would work better for your situation?