# RowGrouping and Subtotal on Datatable For Currency column

Tags: javascript

Hi how to concat $ symbol to group Total of Currency For Example $1,200 curreltly it is 1200 , I am referring to below artcle
[RowGrouping and Subtotal on Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657724/rowgrouping-and-subtotal-on-datatable)